# C# MVC - Call external class within the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, view

I have a view that that nedds to use an external **static** content provide.
this is how I try to access it:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<NameSpace.ActionsMetadata.BrokerAction>" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <%
                OpenDemoAccount content =  NameSpace.Models.ActionsMetadata.Translations.ContentGroupsHolder();
            %>
```

But I can't this way for some reason. How do I access the external class within the view?
(in the first line I am using this: `NameSpace.ActionsMetadata.BrokerAction` user data )

Comment: @svinto - that NameSpace.Models.ActionsMetadata.Translations.ContentGroupsHolder() is a type and it is not valid in the giving context

Comment: Maybe your forgot to add "new" keyword before NameSpace.Models.ActionsMetadata.Translations.ContentGroupsHolder()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view really has no business accessing this global state directly - this should be the responsibility of the Controller. It would be more in line with the MVC paradigm if the Controller accessed this data, and put it in the ViewBag for the view to utilize..

```
// In controller...
ViewBag.OpenDemoAccount = NameSpace.Models.ActionsMetadata.Translations.ContentsGroupHolder();

// In view...
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%
        OpenDemoAccount content = ViewBag.OpenDemoAccount;
    %>
```

EDIT:

For MVC 2 the code will be slightly different:

```
// In controller...
ViewData["OpenDemoAccount"] = NameSpace.Models.ActionsMetadata.Translations.ContentsGroupHolder();

// In view...
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%
        OpenDemoAccount content = (OpenDemoAccount)ViewData["OpenDemoAccount"];
    %>
```

Comment: Thanks, The ViewBag is not in my context of the controller

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: version 3 but not the razor method... must i change to razor?

Comment: no, it's not specific for Razor... it should be available in the Controller - http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/19/ViewBagAspNetMvc3.aspx

Comment: I just figured that I am using version 2 and not 3, Im gonna find how to upgrade... thanks

Comment: ahh in that case you need to use ViewData instead of ViewBag, see edit